# how to have a background of a container inside header from start to the end of full width of a page?

Tags: html, css

Here I am trying to extend the background of the title from first to the end of the full width of the page. The title is inside a div container. I need to get the result like shown in the image. Here's my code.[image: Title with half height background from start to the end]

```css
.whoweare h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #EE4036;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 80px auto;
    background: #FCE1D8;
  }
```

```html
<section class="whoweare" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is how to get the skewed background

```css
.whoweare h1{
  display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #EE4036;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: relative;
  }

.whoweare h1::after{
  content: "";
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100px;
  width: calc(100% + 400px);
  height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="whoweare" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No. it doesn't get the full width. it remains inside the container. and also can you show me how to design the starting of the background (cross) like shown in the image and how to make the bg half height of the font?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to create the skewed background, like in the image. I'm confused about what else you are trying to do though...

Comment: Can you check the demo in full page view. The background not full width.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but yeah it's not full width and both of the end is skewed. This would be great if you could make only one end skewed and full width.

Comment: This is how to skew only 1 side: https://codepen.io/Sh_02/pen/OKRzaO